# Header on a table with grouped rows

Tags: gui-design, tables, column-headers

I have a table that looks like this crude paint drawing

[image: Example Table]

The table represents employees grouped by the company they belong to.  I have a table header for the Company (name, address, city, state, etc.).  How do I add a header to the employees to make it more clear what is being displayed?  Particularly the non-obvious fields such as `40` and `2004`.

I've explored two options I am not thrilled about:

1. Adding an indented header under the company header.  This looks strange and it makes it hard to line up the values with your eyes.
2. Adding a header on each and every company grouping.  This is redundant and looks strange for companies with few employees.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Isn't the most common way to show the normal row headers and no headers for the group? The group name (row) should be self-describing. Checkout samples like http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0-ea/examples/kitchensink/#grouped-grid

Comment: @Timo generally, yes.  But the group also has some numbers that need headings to describe what they are, I didn't include that in my drawing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a tabular data table is not best way to display this information? Perhaps consider using the card UI metaphor where you can dedicate more space to data and their labels:

[image]

Note: depending on the data, some information does not need a label because the data describes their purpose.

Comment: This could work.  I still feel it is repetitive, but I can't argue it looks bad.  Thank you!